# Concatenate columns of Pandas dataframe into a new column of lists with only non-zero values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe that looks like:

```
mwe5a = pd.DataFrame({'a': [0.1, 0.0],
                      'b': [0.0, 0.2],
                      'c': [0.3, 0.0]
                    }
                   )
mwe5a

    a      b       c
0   0.1    0.0     0.3
1   0.0    0.2     0.0
```

My desired output is:

```
mwe5b

output_column
[0.1, 0.3]
[0.2]
```

How do I do that?

After that, I'd like to sort the order of a column in another Pandas dataframe based on those values, from largest value to least.

```
mwe7a = pd.DataFrame({'items': [ ['item1', 'item2'],
                                 ['item3']
                               ]})

['item1', 'item2']
['item3']
```

which should then look like

```
mwe7b

['item2', 'item1']
['item3']
```

UPDATE:

I updated the MWE dataframes to be less confusing. So to review, I can get the following to work:

```
token_uniqueness_sparse = pd.DataFrame({'token_a': [0.1, 0.0],
                                        'token_b': [0.0, 0.2],
                                        'token c': [0.3, 0.0]
                                       }
                                      )
token_uniqueness_sparse

token_a token_b token c
0   0.1 0.0 0.3
1   0.0 0.2 0.0

sf_fake = pd.DataFrame({'items': [ ['token_a', 'token_c'],
                                   ['token_b']],
                        'rcol': [1,2]
                       })
sf_fake

items   rcol
0   [token_a, token_c]  1
1   [token_b]   2

token_uniqueness_dense = (token_uniqueness_sparse
         .apply(lambda x: list(x[x.ne(0)]), axis=1)
         .to_frame('output_column'))
token_uniqueness_dense

output_column
0   [0.1, 0.3]
1   [0.2]

(sf_fake.apply(lambda x: sorted(x['items'], key=lambda y: token_uniqueness_dense.loc[x.name,
 'output_column'][x['items'].index(y)], reverse=True), axis=1))
```

So I know the solution works. But when I attempt to apply it to my actual dataframes and not the toy ones above, I get the following error:

```
Input In [76], in <lambda>(x)
----> 1 (forbes_df.apply(lambda x: sorted(x['tokenized_company_name'], 
      2                                   key=lambda y: tfidf_df_dense.loc[x.name,
      3  'output_column'][x['tokenized_company_name'].index(y)], reverse=True), axis=1))

Input In [76], in <lambda>.<locals>.<lambda>(y)
      1 (forbes_df.apply(lambda x: sorted(x['tokenized_company_name'], 
----> 2                                   key=lambda y: tfidf_df_dense.loc[x.name,
      3  'output_column'][x['tokenized_company_name'].index(y)], reverse=True), axis=1))

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Here's another MWE with samples of my actual data:

```
samp = pd.DataFrame({'tokens': [['berkshire', 'hathaway'],
                        ['icbc'],
                        ['saudi', 'arabian', 'oil', 'company', 'saudi', 'aramco'],
                        ['jpmorgan', 'chase'],
                        ['china', 'construction', 'bank'],
                        []
                       ]})

imp = pd.DataFrame({'importance': [[0.7071067811865476, 0.7071067811865476],
                             [1.0],
                             [0.3779598156018814, 0.39838548612653973, 0.39838548612653973, 0.3285496573358837, 0.6570993146717674],
                             [0.7071067811865476, 0.7071067811865476],
                             [0.4225972188244829, 0.510750779645552, 0.7486956870005814],
                             []
                            ]})
```

Any ideas what to check for?

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution:

```
mwe5b = (mwe5a
         .apply(lambda x: list(x[x.ne(0)].sort_values(ascending=False)), axis=1)
         .to_frame('output_column'))
```

Output:

```
  output_column
0    [0.3, 0.1]
1         [0.2]
```

**EDIT**

To accomplish the goal the OP wants with `mwe7a`, I offer the following solution:

```
(mwe7a.apply(lambda x: sorted(x['items'], key=lambda y: mwe5b.loc[x.name,
 'output_column'][x['items'].index(y)], reverse=True), axis=1))
```

To get `mwe5b` without sorting, as needed for getting `mwe7a`:

```
mwe5b = (mwe5a
         .apply(lambda x: list(x[x.ne(0)]), axis=1)
         .to_frame('output_column'))
```

Output:

```
0    [item2, item1]
1           [item3]
```

Comment: thanks but that sorts the dataframe of values, `mwe5a`, not the dataframe of items, `mwe7a`. I need to sort `mwe7a` based on `mwe7b`

Comment: I like your answer!

Comment: I also put a like on your question, @user2205916. I am going to edit my solution soon to accomplish what you further need.

Comment: Please, @user2205916, see my edited solution, for a solution to get the wanted `mwe7b`. Nice question!

Comment: thanks, great answer. So I can get your solution to work on my MWE, but I get an error on my actual data frames. More info in the "UPDATE:" section of my post. Any ideas on what I can check to resolve this error?

Comment: Without a piece of your datasets, it is quite hard or even impossible to discern the cause of the reported errors. So, I would suggest you to post a piece of your datasets to allow us to help you, @user2205916.

Comment: Point well-received. I've added an MWE of my actual data at the bottom of my original post. Appreciate your assistance

Comment: My solution works in the case you added, if you, @user2205916, fix the cause of the problem: The list `['saudi', 'arabian', 'oil', 'company', 'saudi', 'aramco']` has got 6 elements, but the corresponding line in the other dataframe has got only 5 elements! The corresponding lists *must* have the same size.